# The name datetime is not permitted SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to insert the following query into my table

```
insert into leave 
values ('0101', 'ibrahim shaikh', (datetime, '26-11-2016', 105), (datetime, '26-11-2016', 105), '1', 'nov', '0', 'test', '2016', '0', '11', '1')
```

but I am getting the error

> Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The name "datetime" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Date format in my table is `2016-11-07`

How do I need to write my insert query?

Comment: That's not how you cast a literal to a datetime in SQL Server. Use `CONVERT` instead.

Comment: Just to add to @Nick.McDermaid comment, checkout the documentation for [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx) like

```
insert into leave 
values('0101','ibrahim shaikh',CONVERT(datetime,'26-11-2016',105),CONVERT(datetime,'26-11-2016',105),'1','nov','0','test','2016','0','11','1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `Convert(datetime, '26-11-2016', 105)`.